# Gluon Mobile - Android: Ask for location permission when accessing location

Tags: android, gluon-mobile, runtime-permissions

We display the users location on a map in our Gluon based app. This works fine (with some smaller things we still have to tweak), as long as the user has "location" turned on. However, when it is not turned on, the app crashes. The "AndroidManifest.xml" contains the needed permission lines. We tried several Android versions, starting from 5.1.1 to 6.0.1 up to 7.1.1, to check if it is related to the Android version itself.

On the other hand, when we use our app on an iPhone, the system handles this request and prompts the user to allow access to the location. Even if the user **denies**, the app does **not** crash.

Is there a way to implement the same behaviour for Android?

Edit for better understanding:
jfxmobile version 1.3.10

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="ch" android:versionCode="1"
          android:versionName="0.9.6 Beta">
    <supports-screens android:xlargeScreens="true"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="21" android:targetSdkVersion="23"/>

    <application android:label="BodenDok" android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication"
                 android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
                 android:largeHeap="true">
        <activity android:name="javafxports.android.FXActivity" android:label="BodenDok"
                  android:screenOrientation="portrait"
                  android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize">
            <meta-data android:name="main.class" android:value="ch.BodenDok"/>
            <meta-data android:name="debug.port" android:value="0"/>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <!-- Permission request, Android 23+ -->
        <activity android:name="com.gluonhq.impl.charm.down.plugins.android.PermissionRequestActivity" />

        <activity android:name="com.gluonhq.impl.charm.down.plugins.android.NotificationActivity"
                  android:parentActivityName="javafxports.android.FXActivity">
            <meta-data android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                       android:value="javafxports.android.FXActivity"/>
        </activity>
        <receiver android:name="com.gluonhq.impl.charm.down.plugins.android.AlarmReceiver" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'org.javafxports:jfxmobile-plugin:1.3.10'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'org.javafxports.jfxmobile'
apply plugin: 'checkstyle'

ext.checkstyleVersion    = '8.3'

repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven {
        url 'http://nexus.gluonhq.com/nexus/content/repositories/releases'
    }
}

mainClassName = 'ch.BodenDok'

dependencies {
    compile 'com.gluonhq:charm:5.0.0'
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.controlsfx/controlsfx
    compile group: 'org.controlsfx', name: 'controlsfx', version: '8.40.14'

    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}

jfxmobile {
    downConfig {
        version = '3.8.0'
        // Do not edit the line below. Use Gluon Mobile Settings in your project context menu instead
        plugins 'compass', 'display', 'lifecycle', 'local-notifications', 'magnetometer', 'pictures', 'position', 'runtime-args', 'settings', 'share', 'statusbar', 'storage'
    }
    android {
        manifest = 'src/android/AndroidManifest.xml'
        compileSdkVersion = 25
    }
    ios {
        infoPList = file('src/ios/Default-Info.plist')
        forceLinkClasses = [
                'com.gluonhq.**.*',
                'javax.annotations.**.*',
                'javax.inject.**.*',
                'javax.json.**.*',
                'org.glassfish.json.**.*'
        ]
    }
}

checkstyle {
    toolVersion ="${checkstyleVersion}"
    configFile = project(':').file('config/checkstyle/checkstyle.xml')
    configProperties = [ "suppressionFile" : project(':').file('config/checkstyle/suppressions.xml')]
}
```

EDIT: It seems like the line

```
 <activity android:name="com.gluonhq.impl.charm.down.plugins.android.PermissionRequestActivity" />
```

suggested by José Pereda was not inside the application-tag. Now Android 7.1.2 show directly the location screen, Android 5.1.1 still crashes the app. Is there any way of asking which Android version is running? E.g. "Platform.Android.version" or "MobileApplication.Android.version" so that we could catch the error accordingly?

Comment: I don't know about Gluon, but for android did you check if the build version < 23? else you need to check if the permission is granted? else you ask for one! maybe if you share your code it would be better to point out what is missing.

Comment: Yes, post your manifest, the build.gradle and jfxmobile version of your project

Comment: Thank you for your answers; I added the code snippets in the original post above.

As far as I understood is, that there was a big change in the permission system from Android 5.1.1 to 6.0.1. We would like to support Android 5.1.1 (version 21) anyway. Is this somehow possible to achieve for both versions?

Answer (score 0):

Well, the Trick is to use the explicit Broadcast Receiver here. In this code when the GPS is not connected or is turned off, a dialogue box will be shown alerting you about the NO Gps connection clicking "retry" will take you to the settings page where you will be able to switch on GPS.

**Explicit method for Broadcast Receiver**

```
 private BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
  @Override
  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
      if (intent.getAction().matches("android.location.PROVIDERS_CHANGED")) {
          checkGPS();
      }

  }  };
```

**For asking the permissions from the user (Runtime Permissions)**

```
  public boolean checkLocationpermission() {
  if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
      if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)) {
          ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[] {
              Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
          }, 1001);
      } else {
          ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[] {
              Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
          }, 1003);

      }
      return false;
  } else
      return true;  }
```

**CheckGps method**

```
 public void checkGPS() {
 builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
 builder.setTitle("NO GPS");
 if (isGPSready()) {
     System.out.println("GPs Connected");
 } else {
     builder.setPositiveButton("Retry", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
         @Override
         public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
             if (!isGPSready()) {
                 startActivityForResult(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS), 1001);

                 builder.show();
             } else if (isGPSready()) {
                 System.out.println("the connection is succsful");

             }
         }
     }).setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
         @Override
         public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
             finish();
         }
     });
     builder.show();
 } }
```

**onActivityResult Method**

```
 protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
   if (requestCode == 1001) {
       if (mLocationManager == null) {
           mLocationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
       } else if (!mLocationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {
           checkGPS();
       }

   }
   super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);   }
```

**Here is the full code**

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder;
LocationManager mLocationManager;

private BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getAction().matches("android.location.PROVIDERS_CHANGED")) {
            //isGPSready();
            checkGPS();
        }

    }
};
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    checkLocationpermission();
    checkGPS();
    registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, new IntentFilter(LocationManager.PROVIDERS_CHANGED_ACTION));
}
public boolean isGPSready() {
    mLocationManager = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
    return mLocationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
}

public void checkGPS() {
    builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setTitle("NO GPS");
    builder.setMessage("Click on Retry to get connected to GPS");
    if (isGPSready()) {
        System.out.println("GPs Connected");
    } else {
        builder.setPositiveButton("Retry", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                if (!isGPSready()) {
                    startActivityForResult(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS), 1001);
                    builder.show();
                } else if (isGPSready()) {
                    System.out.println("the connection is succsful");

                }
            }
        }).setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                finish();
            }
        });
        builder.show();
    }

}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == 1001) {
        if (mLocationManager == null) {
            mLocationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
        } else if (!mLocationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {
            checkGPS();
        }

    }
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

}

public boolean checkLocationpermission() {
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[] {
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
            }, 1001);
        } else {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[] {
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
            }, 1003);
            mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this);
        }
        return false;
    } else
        return true;
}}
```

Comment: I don't think you need to implement this on your own... as it is already there. If you check the Javadoc for Down 3.8.0, there is a `PermissionRequest` activity included, for the `Position` [service](http://docs.gluonhq.com/charm/javadoc/5.0.0/index.html?com/gluonhq/charm/down/package-summary.html) or others. See also `Runtime permissions request on Android` in this [post](http://gluonhq.com/new-gluon-charm-services-part/).

Comment: karan:
Thank you for your explanation - since we are relatively new to app programming, we appreciate your answer a lot! :)

@JoséPereda: We figured out, that we had the runtime permission request already - but it was outside of the <application>-tag.